# Sacar lo anterior a los últimos 10 días desde el día de hoy - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Quería hacer una búsqueda que me sacara todo lo anterior a los últimos 10 días en base al día en el que estamos.

Ejemplo: Hoy es día 11/04/2022, quiero que saque todo lo anterior a 10 días desde hoy, por lo cual seria lo anterior al 01/04/2022. Como es algo que tendré que revisar diariamente, quería que fuera dinámica, para que sea el día que sea muestre siempre lo anterior a 10 días.

¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problemas has tenido? Pulsa en [edit] y mejora tu pregunta. Lee [ask].

Comment: ¿Algo como lo que dice la documentación? ¿`db.collection.find(query)` donde el objeto query representa el campo por el que deseas filtrar y su valor es un operador de comparación? Faltan muchos detalles a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Tal como está redactada sólo puedo indicarte que te dirijas a la documentación y **leas**. De nada! Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Di con ello, no lo conseguía y esta mañana me desespere, igualmente dejo un ejemplo y la query.

```
db.getCollection("prueba").find({
    "fin": {
        "$lt": new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 10))
    }
}, {
    "fin": 1.0
}).sort({
    "fin": -1.0
});
```

Muchas gracias a @Mauricio Contreras y a @padaleiana, para otra ocasión, intentare ser mas precisa.

Comment: Si esto es parte de la pregunta, debes _editarla_ (y borrar esta _no-respuesta_, si es que no es una respuesta). Recuerda que la pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para otros quienes lleguen a tener un problema similar. Tal como está redactada actualmente tu pregunta, terminaría [cerrada](/help/closed-questions) por _necesitar detalles o aclaraciones_.

Comment: ¿Porqué usas un flotante para el valor de sort y para la proyección?